# Resize matrix by repeating copies of it, in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Say you have two matrices, A is 2x2 and B is 2x7 (2 rows, 7 columns). I want to create a matrix C of shape 2x7, out of copies of A. The problem is np.hstack only understands situations where the column numbers divide (say 2 and 8, thus you can easily stack 4 copies of A to get C) ,but what about when they do not? Any ideas?

```
A = [[0,1]      B = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],   C = [[0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
     [2,3]]          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]        [2,3,2,3,2,3,2]]
```

Comment: Please include the code you've written so far.

Comment: added sample case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach with `modulus` -

```
In [23]: ncols = 7 # No. of cols in output array

In [24]: A[:,np.mod(np.arange(ncols),A.shape[1])]
Out[24]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]])
```

Or with `%` operator -

```
In [27]: A[:,np.arange(ncols)%A.shape[1]]
Out[27]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]])
```

For such repeated indices, using [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) would be more performant -

```
In [29]: np.take(A, np.arange(ncols)%A.shape[1], axis=1)
Out[29]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution is very nice. Another possible way would be to still use hstack, but if you don't want the pattern repeated fully you can use array slicing to get the values you need:

a.shape > `(2,2)`

b.shape > `(2,7)`

`repeats = np.int(np.ceil(b.shape[1]/a.shape[0]))`

`trim = b.shape[1] % a.shape[0]`

`c = np.hstack([a] * repeats)[:,:-trim]`

>

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without numpy (although the np solution posted above is a lot nicer):

```
A = [[0,1],
     [2,3]]

B = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

i_max, j_max = len(A), len(A[0])
C = []
for i, line_b in enumerate(B):
    line_c = [A[i % i_max][j % j_max] for j, _ in enumerate(line_b)]
    C.append(line_c)

print(C)
```